# Invalid resource configuration error while creating AWS IoT Certificate using serverless framework

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-iot

I am trying to create an AWS IoT Thing using Serverless Framework. Following is my YAML file for the same.

I am getting "Error occurred during operation 'Invalid certificate resource configuration'..".

Any clue what the issue can be?

```
service: winds-delivery-infra

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: ap-south-1

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello

resources:
  Resources:
    IoTThing:
      Type: AWS::IoT::Thing
    IoTPolicy:
      Type: AWS::IoT::Policy
      Properties: 
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: ["iot:Connect"]
              Resource: "*"
            - Effect: "Allow"
              Action: ["iot:Publish","iot:Subscribe","iot:Receive"]
              Resource: "*"
    IoTCertificate:
      Type: AWS::IoT::Certificate
      Properties:
        Status: "ACTIVE"
    PolicyPrincipalAttachmentCert:
      Type: AWS::IoT::PolicyPrincipalAttachment
      Properties:
        PolicyName:
          Ref: IoTPolicy
        Principal: { Fn::GetAtt: [IoTCertificate, Arn] }
```

Comment: are there more words in that error message? if so, they might be very helpful

Comment: There is no helpful error message. That is why I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like AWS CloudFormation to issue an IoT certificate for you, you need to tell it your own CSR (Certificate Signing Request). You can, for example, use `openssl` to generate a CSR for you:

```s
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout PRIVATEKEY.key -out MYCSR.csr
```

Once you have your CSR, you can then update your CloudFormation with it as below, and it will work:

```yaml
    IoTCertificate:
      Type: AWS::IoT::Certificate
      Properties:
        Status: "ACTIVE"
        CertificateSigningRequest: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\nMIIE0DCCArgCAQAwg......uOQIKNqgCxzmqy\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n"
```